# ADFS Token generation working in C# but NOT in VB.Net

Tags: c#, vb.net, wcf, adfs, .net-4.6.2

Below is code in c# to get token from server.
The code in C# is working fine and I am able to receive the token from server but when I write same syntax in VB.net then I get exception.

The framework for the code is same "4.6.2". App config of both the code are same.

```
var sEndPointAddress = "url";
WS2007HttpBinding binding = new WS2007HttpBinding();
binding.Security.Message.EstablishSecurityContext = false;
binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.None;
binding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = MessageCredentialType.UserName;
binding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential;

WSTrustChannelFactory trustChannelFactory = new WSTrustChannelFactory(binding, new EndpointAddress("https://IPAddress/adfs/services/trust/13/usernamemixed"));
trustChannelFactory.TrustVersion = TrustVersion.WSTrust13;

trustChannelFactory.Credentials.UserName.UserName = "username";
trustChannelFactory.Credentials.UserName.Password = "password";

RequestSecurityToken requestToken = new RequestSecurityToken(RequestTypes.Issue);
requestToken.AppliesTo = new EndpointReference(sEndPointAddress);
WSTrustChannel tokenClient = (WSTrustChannel)trustChannelFactory.CreateChannel();

var token = tokenClient.Issue(requestToken);
```

I have converted the same code in VB.Net but I am receving exception error.

The server was unable to process the request due to an internal error.  For more information about the error, either turn on IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults (either from ServiceBehaviorAttribute or from the  configuration behavior) on the server in order to send the exception information back to the client, or turn on tracing as per the Microsoft .NET Framework SDK documentation and inspect the server trace logs.

Below is code in VB.Net

```
Dim sEndPointAddress As String = "url"
Dim binding As New WS2007HttpBinding()
binding.Security.Message.EstablishSecurityContext = False
binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.None
binding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = MessageCredentialType.UserName
binding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential


Dim trustChannelFactory As New WSTrustChannelFactory(binding, New EndpointAddress("https://IPAddress/adfs/services/trust/13/usernamemixed"))
trustChannelFactory.TrustVersion = TrustVersion.WSTrust13
trustChannelFactory.Credentials.UserName.UserName = "username"
trustChannelFactory.Credentials.UserName.Password = "password"

Dim requestToken As New RequestSecurityToken(RequestTypes.Issue)
requestToken.AppliesTo = New EndpointReference(sEndPointAddress)

Dim tokenClient As WSTrustChannel = CType(trustChannelFactory.CreateChannel(), WSTrustChannel)
Dim token As Object = tokenClient.Issue(requestToken)
```

Comment: Looks mostly identical to me.  The very last line should omit the `As Object` and compile with `Option Infer On` to be the same as the C#, but that shouldn't produce an error.

Comment: @Craig I have already tried that. The object which is returned is "SecurityToken". But still the issue persist.